# WinForms ListView C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have two problems with a `ListView` I am using.

My `ListView` is set as `ListViewView.View = List` and I am adding a few items to it, via `ListView.Items.Add(string)`.

The first one, I notice that for text items that are wider than the width of the `ListView` itself there is no horizontal scroll bad, and I can't seem to find a way to enable it.

The second is that to select an item I need to select click on part of the item itself, rather than the line the item is in. In other words, if I have an item with a really small length, I can't click anywhere on the line to select it, I have to click *on it*.

Here is an the code I have an what I am seeing:

```
listView1.Items.Add("aaaabbbbccccddddffffeeeegggghhhhiiiijjjjkkkkllllmmmmnnnnooooppppqqqqrrrrssssttttuuuuvvvvwwwwxxxxyyyyzzzz");
listView1.Items.Add("a");
```

[image]

As you can see from the image above there are no scroll bars and the length of the text on `Index[0]` is much wider than the width of the `ListView`

Likewise on `Index[1]` where the text is just a single `a`, to select it I have to click directly on top of the `a` rather than anywhere else in the line.

Is there a way of fixing these two problems easily?

Also the reason why I'm using a ListView is because I want to add images to the items.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need a ListView? Why not use a ListBox?

Comment: This is a byproduce of setting your listview in List mode. If you use details mode this could be avoided.

Comment: @YacoubMassad the original question states at the very end why a ListView: I need to put images next to the text on the row. You can't (easily) do that with a ListBox.

Comment: I think to use `Detail` instead of `List` as `View` would be more appropriate for your needs. And `ListView` has a `FullRowSelect` property that might help you.

Comment: Would not real data have a space or two in it to allow line wrapping?

Comment: @RenéVogt I've tried the `FullRowSelect`, but it only works with `Detail`. I was trying to steer way from the `Detail` `View` but looks like I'll have to go down that root

Comment: @TaW spaces or no spaces the result is the same. On another note have you ever dealt with German words? Trust me some can be *really* big.

Comment: Big? Yes, that big? No. And: In a ListView you should abreviate them.. Rene 's comment solves all your questions, Details shows scrollbars and with HeaderStyle.None it will look just like a List..

Answer (score 0):

For your second problem just set the FullRowSelect to `true` in properties or you can do `listview1.FullRowSelect = true;`